# How to Escape or Sanitize ACF get_field () and the out put of Wysiwyg Editor output?

Tags: escaping, advanced-custom-fields, sanitization, acfpro

Can i know how to be Escape proper way ACF(advanced custom filed )  , get_field () option and Wysiwyg Editor output ?    is that wp_kses option to be applied?

is this statement right?

```html
<?php   
$quote = wp_kses_post( get_field('quote', 'options') );
         
echo' <p> '. wp_kses_post($quote) .' </p>'; 

?>
```